# using isset($_POST['upload']){ ... } and calling it on form input type file change and not the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

In my php page,
I have a form as:

```
   <form enctype = 'multipart/form-data' method="post">

        Select File:
        <br/>
        <input type="file" name="file" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />

    </form>
```

When I submit the form on clicking the submit 'upload', the following php is called which is on the same php page:

```
<?php
       if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {  ...Do stuff... } 
?>
```

Now, I dont want to use the submit in my html form and want to trigger this php whenever a file in the input type file is selected. i.e. the form should be submitted automatically on file selection without the submit button. Also, i want a if condition such as isset($_POST['']) and dont want to use just a post check as $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could accomplish this by placing a js event listener on the file input.  When this 'changed' listener fires, submit your form using js.  Give this a try, and if you stumble along the way, post your attempt here.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to set an event handle for change in input file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $("input:file").change(function (){
   $('form').submit();
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What if I have another form also having a input type as 'file' ? That I suppose will also trigger it.

Comment: set an id or class to all form

Comment: `$('#customIDtoInputtypeFile').change(function(){});`